# Why i get different number of response headers while using Postman and Angular HttpClient?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-3.1, response-headers

I use asp.net core 3.1 web API to create a response and this is the default template in visual studio. When I call the API on Postman I see 5 response headers but when I call HttpClient.Get (Angular 9) with type 'observe: response' and examine response headers I see only 2 headers

```
  showConfig() {
this.getConfig()
  .subscribe(
    resp => {
      const keys = resp.headers.keys();
      this.responseText = keys;
      // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-for-of
      for (let i = 0 ; i < keys.length ; i++) {
        this.responseText[i] += '  ' + resp.headers.get(this.responseText[i]);
      }
      this.WR = resp.body.pop();
    }
  );
```

}

Comment: Are the missing headers related to cookies?

Comment: I think it is related to the HttpClient Object because user agents are different in these scenarios.